# Why are git submodules not cloned when using git clone --recursive?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

My git submodule clone is not working.

The repository in question is [this](https://github.com/0xNOY/0xNOY.github.io).

I have run roughly the following commands.

```bash
hugo new site 0xNOY.github.io
cd 0xNOY.github.io
git init
git submodule add https://github.com/CaiJimmy/hugo-theme-stack/ themes/stack
# Edit some files
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
# and push to GitHub
```

I then ran `git clone --recursive git@github.com:0xNOY/0xNOY.github.io.git` from GitHub to local on another PC to clone it. However, the submodules were never cloned.

I also tried the following commands and others, but submodules were never cloned without any errors or other indications.

```bash
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

```bash
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

#### Environments

- git: 2.40.1

Answer (score 0):

Running `git submodule add ...` again solved the problem heh